# Is it possible to extend JQuery using Typescript by making a subclass of it?

Tags: jquery, typescript

I want to add some minor methods, but I do not want to add them to the JQuery-Interface.

I thought of a global function X(...) (called like $(...) ) which would make a JQuery object with the given parameters, downcast it to my subclass, add the additionals methods and return this object.

Comment: [Create a plugin instead.](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/)

Comment: As I understood, the plugin would change the JQuery-behaviour for all my JQuery-Objects. The Methods should only appear for my Subclass (using intellisense in VS)

Comment: Plugins are how jQuery is *designed* to work. I suspect you're improperly applying C#-type thinking to JavaScript programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick answer is that you can't extend jQuery in TypeScript because it isn't represented as a class. The longer answer is below.

Because jQuery is not implemented (or declared) as a class, you can't create a sub-class that extends it in TypeScript.

For example, many declarations in TypeScript for third-party libraries follow an interface-var style like this:

```
interface CoolLibrary {
    coolStuff(size: number): string;
}

declare var cool: CoolLibrary;
```

This means you get type information and auto-completion for the library, but you can't extend it.

If you know that the library can be extended, you could declare it as such:

```
declare class CoolLibrary {
    coolStuff(size: number): string;
}

declare var cool: CoolLibrary;
```

You could then create sub-classes of CoolLibrary to extend its behaviour.

Normally, the reason you don't declare the third-party library in this way is that you either know it cannot be extended or you can't guarantee it will remain so.